# Simple jsfiddle example not working

Tags: html, css

I know that a lot of question are asked like this, but I don't know what to write either than that. This is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CnJF5/2/

HTML: `<div id="myDiv" ></div>`

CSS:

```
#myDiv
{
    background-color:black;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

How can this fiddle make a `div` that is over the hole page and is black?

Comment: There seems to be a question missing.

Comment: @GolezTrol but but but there is a question mark in it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want that div to take up the whole page you need all the parent elements to have `height` set to `100%` as well:

```
body, html {
    height:100%
}

#hider
{
    background-color:black;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CnJF5/8/

Comment: Thank you! I must wait 5 minutes to set your answer as accepted answer.

Comment: All the parents don't have to be necessarily 100%, they can be anything, they just have to have a set height.

Comment: @JuanMendes is right, but if you want it to take up the whole page, they do. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Just to be a PITA: they don't have to be set to 100%, you can set HTML to height:50% and then set your div to be height: 200% http://jsfiddle.net/CnJF5/34/ :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to set

```
body, html {
    height: 100%
}
```

Elements only respect percentage height if their parents have a fixed height.

- http://www.tutwow.com/htmlcss/quick-tip-css-100-height/
- http://jsfiddle.net/CnJF5/11/

Answer (score 0):

100% of what? The default value for `width` and `height` is `auto`. If you want a black page you need to give the `<div>`'s ancestors some values also.

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this... http://jsfiddle.net/CnJF5/12/

```
#myDiv {
    z-index: 10000;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50); /*older IE*/
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=50); /* IE */
    -moz-opacity: .50; /*older Mozilla*/
    -khtml-opacity: 0.5;   /*older Safari*/
    opacity: 0.5;   /*supported by current Mozilla, Safari, and Opera*/
    background-color:#000000;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}​
```